# Trying to optmize a Hibernate Query with read only

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to optmize a query that is currently taking a little longer than expected. The query returns about 11000 entities, but since they are a bit complicated and have nested entities it's somewhat slow. Since I'm not going to modify the entities, I tried setting the query/session to read-only, but it hasn't helped, it still takes just as long, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Below is a simplified code, sorry it's a little messy:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(value = {@NamedQuery(name = "demand.all", query = "select d from Demand d")})
public class Demand {
    private Long ID;
    private Division division;
    private Client client;
    private Product product;
    private String code;
    ...
}

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Demand> getAll() {
    SessionImpl sessionImpl = ((SessionImpl)em.getDelegate());
    Session session = sessionImpl.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        sessionImpl.connection().setReadOnly(true);
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("demand.all");
        List<Demand> resultList = query.setReadOnly(true).setCacheable(false).setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL).list();
        sessionImpl.connection().setReadOnly(false);
        tx.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        resultList = null;
    }
    session.close();
    return resultList;
}
```

I read that making the query read-only is not enough, so I tried setting the connection and transaction read-only too, but I'm not sure if it's necessary. Anyways, am I doing something wrong? What other way is there to optimize this query?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this faster would be fetching the objects in a lazy way or depending on which are necessary and which are not. Like maybe you only need to show 5 columns in a table, instead of every single object in the hierarchy, so you create DTO to get them. If you need more information on one of them.. lets say the user clicks on a row, then you would bring the whole object hierarchy of it..

It may not apply in your case, but its one way of efficiently getting data.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't apply to my case. I use this query when making a copy of part of the database, so I need everything at once.

Comment: humm, can you be a little more specific then? maybe if i have an idea of what you want to do i could help you a little bit more. Copy part of the database for what?

Comment: To save it in a different file, so users can have their own copy and edit it without affecting the database.

Comment: I would create a query, hql or SP that returns everything i need without mapping it to classes as a straight-forward table with joins.. its faster doing it that way since you avoid the need to instantiate and create every single object for every row. or maybe check for cyclic composition of objects (parent has child, child has parent)